# How to listen firefox has quitted/restarted events with their extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a firefox extension that listens when the firefox has launched using

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data)
{
if(topic == "app-startup")
{

}
```

similarly how to listen the firefox quit/restart event using javascript.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register to observe `quit-application-requested` (self-explanatory) or `quit-application` (the app is about to quit, either in response to a shutdown or a restart).

You can find a big list of observer topics on this page:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications

**Note:** As of Firefox 4 you should no longer be using `app-startup` to register a startup notification. [Use `profile-after-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications) instead.